# ODE in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by the gradient of a function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying for an exam and I got stuck in this question:

Let $x: I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable parametrized curve (I is an interval) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $\frac{dx}{dt}(t) = - \nabla f(x(t))$. Show that either $x$ is a constant function or $f \circ x$ is strictly decreasing.

I tried differentiating $f \circ x$ and arrived to the result that $\frac{d (f \circ x)}{dt} = - \Vert \nabla f(x(t)) \Vert ^2 \leq 0$, which proves that $f \circ x$ is monotonically decreasing. I concluded that to show the desired result, it must be the case that if $\nabla f(x(c)) = 0$ for some $c \in I$, then $\nabla f(x(t)) = 0$ for all $t \in I$, but I can't understand or prove it. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops, the question as stated is wrong.  Consider $n=1$ with 
$$ f(x) = \cases{- |x|^{3/2} & for $x < 0$\cr
                 0 & for $x \ge 0$}
$$
and
$$ x(t) = \cases{-9 t^2/16 & for $t > 0$\cr
                0 & for $t \le 0$} $$
Note that 
$$ \nabla f(x) = \cases{- 3 |x|^{1/2}/2 & for $x < 0$\cr
                        0 & for $x \ge 0$}$$
so that 
$$ \dfrac{d}{dt} x(t) = \cases{ -9 t/8 & for $t > 0$\cr 0 & for $t \le 0$} = \nabla f(x(t))$$
but $x(t)$ is not constant and $f(x(t))$ is not strictly decreasing.

The problem is that although $\nabla f$ is continuous, it is not Lipschitz, so the
hypothesis of the [Picard–Lindelöf uniqueness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) for differential equations is not satisfied.  It would work if $f$ was, say, $C^2$.